# Interview Q: How many ways to construct tower of Lego bricks?

Tags: math, dynamic-programming

I [found this problem online](http://symbo1ics.com/blog/?p=2055), but cannot really find a good way to solve it nicely:

*Given a set of Lego bricks of height 1, 2, 3, and 4, each colored differently, write a program to compute the number of ways of constructing a tower of height n ≥ 1.*

It seems this can be solved with Dynamic Programming, but I am quite inexperienced in this.
Any ideas for a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is thus:

1. Place a brick of size `k`.
2. You are now left with the problem of building a tower of size `n-k`.

Comment: He needs to count the ways, so wouldn't it lead to exponential runtime? How to choose a brick size of k?

Comment: @Mustafa: memoization ;)

Comment: Of all the answers I have seen that repeat the m-1, m-2 recursion, this is the first I've seen to put in words why it works; nicely done

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be something like the following Python function:

```
def lego(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0 # invalid case
    elif n == 0:
        return 1 # solved case
    else:
        return lego(n-1) + lego(n-2) + lego(n-3) + lego(n-4)
```

However, as noted by Oliver, this will have exponential run-time unless you memoize (using something like functools.lru_cache or creating your own memoization decorator if using Python, for example) it.

Nevertheless, there exist even better ways of doing this. For example, you can do something similar to the matrix method of generating Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Well this nice algorithm can be done with a simple for-loop, on a circular array that only remembers the 4 last values of lego tower sizes.

```
int lego_tower(int n)
{
    int lego[4] = {1, 0, 0, 0}, i;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        lego[i&3] += lego[(i+1) & 3] + lego[(i+2) & 3] + lego[(i+3) & 4];

    return lego[n&3];
}
```

Note that `i & 3` is the same as `i % 4`, and that this i+3 is i-1 (modulo 4), i+2 is i-2, and so on, thus you recognize the recursive formula of other answers :

> lego_tower(n) == lego_tower(n-4) + lego_tower(n-3) + lego_tower(n-2) + lego_tower(n-1)

The initialization says that for i=0, you have 1 way of building the tower, all other ways (-1 to -3) are impossible, thus 0 ways of building the tower.